# TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable AudioMetaData object

Tags: python, torchaudio

https://github.com/facebookresearch/svoice/issues/94

Using dependencies:

```
$ pip list
Package Version

antlr4-python3-runtime 4.8
audioread 3.0.1
certifi 2023.7.22
cffi 1.16.0
charset-normalizer 3.3.0
colorama 0.4.6
colorlog 6.7.0
decorator 5.1.1
filelock 3.12.4
fsspec 2023.9.2
hydra-colorlog 1.0.0
hydra-core 1.0.3
idna 3.4
Jinja2 3.1.2
joblib 1.3.2
librosa 0.7.1
llvmlite 0.41.0
MarkupSafe 2.1.3
mpmath 1.3.0
networkx 3.1
numba 0.58.0
numpy 1.25.2
omegaconf 2.1.2
pesq 0.0.2
Pillow 10.0.1
pip 23.2.1
pycparser 2.21
pystoi 0.3.3
PyYAML 6.0.1
requests 2.31.0
resampy 0.4.2
scikit-learn 1.3.1
scipy 1.11.3
setuptools 68.2.2
six 1.16.0
soundfile 0.12.1
sympy 1.12
threadpoolctl 3.2.0
torch 2.1.0
torchaudio 2.1.0
torchvision 0.16.0
tqdm 4.51.0
typing_extensions 4.8.0
urllib3 2.0.6
```

ERROR:

```
$ ./make_debug.sh
0%| | 0/8 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
File "", line 88, in _run_code
File "D:\auditivo.ai\svoice\svoice\data\audio.py", line 87, in
json.dump(find_audio_files(sys.argv[1]), sys.stdout, indent=4)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\auditivo.ai\svoice\svoice\data\audio.py", line 34, in find_audio_files
siginfo, _ = torchaudio.info(file)
^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable AudioMetaData object
0%| | 0/8 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
File "", line 88, in _run_code
File "D:\auditivo.ai\svoice\svoice\data\audio.py", line 87, in
json.dump(find_audio_files(sys.argv[1]), sys.stdout, indent=4)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\auditivo.ai\svoice\svoice\data\audio.py", line 34, in find_audio_files
siginfo, _ = torchaudio.info(file)
^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable AudioMetaData object
0%| | 0/8 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
File "", line 88, in _run_code
File "D:\auditivo.ai\svoice\svoice\data\audio.py", line 87, in
json.dump(find_audio_files(sys.argv[1]), sys.stdout, indent=4)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\auditivo.ai\svoice\svoice\data\audio.py", line 34, in find_audio_files
siginfo, _ = torchaudio.info(file)
^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable AudioMetaData object
(auditivo)
```

Dependencies to be installed

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to downgrade your version of torchaudio for now (pip install torchaudio==0.7.0 should do the trick) I hope it's helpful to you.

Comment: $ pip install torchaudio==0.7.0
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution ~orch (C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages)
ERROR: Ignored the following yanked versions: 2.0.0
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torchaudio==0.7.0 (from versions: 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.1.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torchaudio==0.7.0


I always have this kind of a problem where it is not able to find the correct version.

A similar thing happened with this comment. 
pip install torch==1.6.0+cu101 torchvision==0.7.0+cu101 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).